Meaning of "le luth" in 19th century French piano score
I'm looking at a piano concerto by Henri-Joseph Taskin, from ca. 1800, score here:
https://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Concerto_in_D_major%2C_Op.2_(Taskin%2C_Henri-Joseph)
And I'm seeing a frequent notation in the solo part saying "le luth".  Now I'm pretty sure that translates to "the lute", though no lute is called for in the orchestration, so it's clearly not a literal lute.  (And even if there was an actual lute, why mention it in the piano part?)

My guess is that this relates to the pedals, as each instance is followed several measures later by "otez le pedalle", which would mean "take off the pedal".  But playing it that way on the sustain pedal sounds really messy - generally you only hold the pedal for a measure or two if that, and these statements are often many measures apart.
I don't think it's the soft pedal, that's usually marked "una corde"/"tres cordes" or something to that effect.
Thinking maybe it's that middle pedal?  I don't believe I've ever seen any score call that pedal out before.  If so, my piano is not equipped to play it, as it has a mandolin rail on the middle pedal instead (That makes it sound kind of like a harpsichord rather than a mandolin, despite the name.  But it definitely doesn't sound anything like a lute.)  And even when I've played more traditional pianos, I don't recall that middle pedal being at all lute-like in sound.
It's also possible given the age of this score that it refers to some feature not found on most modern pianos for whatever reason.
Edit: For anyone curious to hear this piece, my rendition can be found here: 


I opted to change the sound to that of an acoustic guitar when the pedal is in use.  You can hear it briefly in the first movement around 6:45 (which is where the passage in the image above is heard), but it is featured most prominently in the third, starting at 13:57.

Thanks for adding the picture, wasn't sure it was necessary when it's all text.  Also for correcting "pedle" to "pedalle" - it is often abbreviated to just "pedle" in the score though, with the "le" in superscript.

Érard, a major piano manufacturer of the day, built pianos with four pedals:

From left to right the Erard
pedals are: 1. peau de buffle (also known as “jeu de luth” or “jeu de
harpe”); 2. damper (also known as “la grande pédale”); 3. céleste
(which on Viennese pianos we usually refer to as the “moderator”); and 4. una corda. (Beethoven and His French Piano, Tom Beghin — Liner notes, page 28)1


The mute pedal (No. 1) brings
a batten covered in soft leather to bear on the strings at a point
just behind the nut (the nut is the strip of wood glued to the wrest
plank across which the strings run). Depressing the pedal causes the
batten to slide sideways up a series of triangular, ramp-like guides
on the wrest plank, bringing it into contact with all the strings simultaneously. (Ibid., 67)


The lute pedal created a pizzicato-type sound. (Wikipedia)2

Taskin, being French, likely either used an Érard piano, or perhaps one similarly constructed.

1 Available at https://static.qobuz.com/goodies/18/000138481.pdf
2 All sorts of "novelty" pedals were available as the piano was being developed. A personal favorite is the "Janissary" pedal, which features importantly in the below recording of Mozart's "Rondo alla Turca".




Well, that definitely seems like what's going on here.  Now I suppose the question would be how I go about reproducing this sound on a modern instrument?  Or in MuseScore for that matter, but that'd be a separate question.  I could just mark pizzicato on those sections and see how that works, but I suspect it won't be quite authentic.  Also curious why that pedal went out of style, seemingly very shortly after as I've looked at a lot of French music from that time period and this is the first time I've seen it.

@DarrelHoffman one of the motivations for the “historical performance” movement is that effects like this are lost on modern instruments.

One new thing I just learned about the composer in my research was that he was working for his uncle, Pascal-Joseph Taskin, who was a well-known manufacturer of harpsichords and pianos at the time.  So it might not have been an Érard piano, but rather one from his own shop that was intended.  At the very least, he'd have had an inside track on the various (sometimes literal) bells and whistles being experimented with on instruments of the time.
